# Twitter data using tweepy and Python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

Here is the python code I'm using to pull Twitter data and put them in a mongo collection.

---

```
class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
            db = client['cwc15']
            collection = db['cricket']
            doc = json.loads(data)      #Convert tweet json to dict
            info = {}
            blob = TextBlob(doc[u'text'])
            for sentence in blob.sentences:
                Senti = (sentence.sentiment.polarity)
                if 1 >= Senti > 0.05:
                    Sentiment = "Positive"
                elif -0.05 <= Senti <= 0.05:
                    Sentiment = "Neutral"
                elif -1 <= Senti < -0.05:
                    Sentiment = "Negative"
            info['createdat'] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(doc[u'created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
            info['ISOdate'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(doc[u'created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
            info['Text'] = doc[u'text']
            #print info['Text']
            info['ID'] = doc[u'id']
            info['Source'] = doc[u'source']
            info['Retweeted'] = doc[u'retweeted']
            info['coordinates'] = doc[u'coordinates']
            info['geo'] = doc[u'geo']
            info['Tweet Language'] = doc[u'lang']
            info['In Reply to Screen Name'] = doc[u'in_reply_to_screen_name']
            info['Retweet Count'] = doc[u'retweet_count']
            info['User Name']= doc[u'user'][u'name']
            info['User Description'] = doc[u'user'][u'description']
            info['User Location'] = doc[u'user'][u'location']
            info['User Followers Count'] = doc[u'user'][u'followers_count']
            info['User Handle'] = doc[u'user'][u'screen_name']
            info['User Language'] = doc[u'user'][u'lang']
            info['Time Zone'] = doc[u'user'][u'time_zone']
            info['UTC Offset'] = doc[u'user'][u'utc_offset']
            info['User Favourites Count'] = doc[u'user'][u'favourites_count']
            info['User Friends Count'] = doc[u'user'][u'friends_count']
            info['hashtags'] = []
            for j in doc[u'entities'][u'hashtags']:
                info['hashtags'].append(j[u'text'].encode('utf-8'))
            info['hashtags'] = ', '.join(info['hashtags'])
            info['URLs'] = []
            for k in doc[u'entities'][u'urls']:
                info['URLs'].append(k[u'url'].encode('utf-8'))
            info['URLs'] = ', '.join(info['URLs'])
            info['Sentiment Score'] = Senti
            info ['Sentiment'] = Sentiment
            info['User Location'] = [x.strip().encode('utf-8').lower() for x in re.split(',|/|\|:|;|&',info['User Location'])]
            locationcode=''
            geolocation = ''
            for a in range(len(info['User Location'])):
                val=info['User Location'][a]
                if val in city.keys():
                    locationcode=city[val]
                if val in country.keys() :
                    locationcode=country[val]
                if val in cityloc.keys() :
                    geolocation = cityloc[val]
                if val in countryloc.keys() :
                    geolocation = countryloc[val]
                if locationcode:
                    break
            info['Country Code'] = locationcode
            info['Geolocation'] = geolocation
            collection.insert(info)
            return True

        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed ondata,',str(e)
            time.sleep(5)
            pass
        exit()

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #trackthis = raw_input("Enter the word(s)/ hashtag(s) you want to track:") #To enter hashtag at prompt
    city = {}
    country = {}
    cityloc = {}
    countryloc = {}
    print 'comes here'
    reader =csv.reader(open("CityLocation.csv","rb"))
    print 'comes here1'
    for row in reader:
        name = row[1]
        code = row[0]
        if name:
            city[name.lower()] = code

        nam = row[3]
        code = row[0]
        if nam:
            country[nam.lower()] = code

        locname = row[1]
        location = row[2]
        if locname:
            cityloc[locname.lower()] = location

        locnam = row[3]
        location = row[2]
        if locnam:
            countryloc[locnam.lower()] = location


    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    print "Indexing all new tweets for #:"
    i=0
    def start_stream():
        while True:
            try:
                stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)
                stream.filter(track=['#cwc15']) #Enter keyword(s)
                #stream.filter(track=["%s", trackthis]) #User will be prompted to enter keyword
            except:
                continue
    start_stream()
```

This program should essentially pull all tweets with the keyword specified in the program ie, cwc15. But my mongoDB which i have hosted locally does not seem to populate with the data.

I have a feeling it could be because of the "auth" that i'm parsing to the python class.So, I already tried recreating the twitter app with different authentication keys and doesn't seem to work.

Any help is much appreciated!